# What's a good answer?

Tags: discussion

In [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), we can read:

> Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful

A comment can also achieve this goal. I see (so so) many -very- higly scored two or three words answers  just mentioning, for example, something like:

> *Add  `;` !!!!!!*

The *`!`* is there just to fulfill the number of characters required to post.  Many highly scored half-phrase answers exist on this website; ***such answers do not make you learn anything*** but they are tolerated not only in the past but still:  Nowadays, often when I flag in the **Late Answers** queue a  half phrase answer, my flags get also declined/disputed.

I think allowing such posts harms the reputation/credibility of this website and may be it would be good to close the question itself (?)

Shouldn't we  improve *how to answer*?

Comment: Indeed. If that is the answer, the question should be closed.

Comment: You claim that many such answers exist. I'd like some links, so the questions they're on can be closed, where necessary.

Comment: Exactly: I do not want to post links to such answers (that you can find quickly, including probably from the answers of the last hour done both by less or highly reputed members) because my goal is not to attack members personally. @Cerbrus

Comment: Quality control is not a personal attack. If there are bad answers out there, they should be improved or removed. Same for questions. You claim there are many such answers, I'm asking you to back up that claim with some links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "Helpful" answer isn't always *"Good"*, or even the best possible action on the question.

A question that can be answered with *"Add `;`"*, should be closed as:
*"Off-Topic > This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*

We don't need to improve "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)", since "What to answer" is already covered in that page under ***Answer well-asked questions***, at the bottom of the page.

Comment: hey @cerbrus, i have a question about answering questions: do we need to correct all the other mestakes in the showed code or do we just answer the question that was asked? I'm getting downvoted on an answer that I believe IS correct (already deleted it cause it was going to get me in minus karma lol)

Comment: If there's multiple problems in a question, it's always helpful to point out all problems.